# SQL constraint for a variable to start with a letter followd by numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, ddl, check-constraints

I'm a beginner on oracle apex and im trying to implement a constraint that only allows variables in a column that start with a certain letter ('P') and are followed by numeric digits. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`regexp_like`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm#SQLRF00501) operator:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT mytable_field_check
CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (myfiled, 'P[0-9]*'))
```

Comment: I tried before but it prompts me for an invalid relational operator

Comment: @StavrosKasapi please share your exact statement and error message

Comment: found it!!ALTER TABLE Product_SK
ADD CONSTRAINT Product_SK_ProductCode_check
CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (ProductCode,'P[0-9]*'))

Comment: @StavrosKasapi Arg, I got caught up in `like`'s syntax. Edited and fixed. Thanks!